# c++ Deleting a number from integer

Tags: c++, loops, printing, int

So I have to write a program that reads two integers and determines whether after deleting any number from the first int, the new one is equal to the second read integer(for example if the input is 123 and 12 it should print out "Yes", because after crossing out the 3, the two ints are equal). I think the code I wrote is correct but the program doesn't print anything. here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned int a, b, temp, len = 0;
    cin >> a >> b;
    temp = a;
    while(temp!=0)
    {
        temp = temp/10;
        len++;
    }

    int k = 1, m = 0, p = 1;

    while (k>len || m == b)
    {  
        for (int i = 1; i<=len-k; i++)
            p = p*10;
        m = a/(p*10)*p + a%p;
        if (m == b)
            cout << "Yes" << endl;
        if (k == len && m!=b)
            cout << "No" << endl;
        k++;
    }

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: "whether after deleting any number from the first int, the new one is equal to the second read integer",
Will this not always be true whenever `first_number>second_number`

Comment: No, the first is always supposed to be bigger - for example if you have 123 and 12 as input, it should print "Yes" - we have crossed out the 3 and the new ints are equal

Comment: Could you please give more example Input and Output?

Comment: 75648 7648 - Yes (after crossing out the 5)
423 41 - No

Comment: and there will be crossed out always exactly one digit, not more than one or zero?

Answer (score 0):

I think that cutting out digits is easier at the level of strings than at the level of integer values. Hence a solution based on strings, which in a loop cuts out the digit and compares the strings.
If it is not about performance but about readable code, I would prefer this solution:

```c
string a, b;
cin >> a;
cin >> b;

bool isContained = false;
size_t aLen = a.length();
for (int i=0; i < aLen; i++) {

    // cuttedOut is a derivation of string a, where the i'th position is cut out
    string cuttedOut = a.substr(0,i) + a.substr (i+1,aLen-1);
    if (cuttedOut == b)
    {
        isContained = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, because "132" and "12" should also match, unless I'm mis-understanding the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i understood the problem:

*Given*: two numbers: **a** and **b** where **a > b**.

*Question*: is it possible to delete exacely one digit in number a (in its decimal representation) so the new value of **a** = **b**

*Examples*:

```
a=12345
b=1245
//lets delete first digit from a. We will get: 2345 != 1245
//lets delete second digit from a. We will get: 1345 != 1245
//lets delete third digit from a. We will get: 1245 == 1245 OK
```

The condition:

```
while (k>len || m == b)
```

is true only when variable **a** or **b** is set to **0**. Other ways it is false, because k=1 and it is not grater than number of digits in variable **a** (minimal **len** value is 1).
Probably there should have been: 

*k < len*.

Next problem is, that you print *"No"* many times, until check all the digits or you found the answer. Try to use some **bool** variable.

Here you have my example:

```
bool almoustEuqal(int a, int b)
{
    if(a<0 && b<0)  //this is for negative number
    {               //so  a=-123    b=-23   =>OK
        a = -a;     //but a=-123    b=-14   =>No
        b = -b;
    }
    if(a < b || a < 10) return false;
    int p = 1, t;
    while(p < a)
    {
        t = a / p / 10;
        t *= p;
        t += a % p;
        if(t == b) return true; //if it's OK then interup loop
        p *= 10;
    }
    return false;   //otherwise return false
}
```

than somewhere in your code just use:

```
//...
std::cin >> a;
std::cin >> b;
if(almoustEuqal(a, b))
{
    std::cout << "Ok";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "No";
}
//or in other way:
std::cout << ((almoustEuqal(a, b)) ? "OK" : "No");
//..
```